# Why isn't this dash omnidirectional?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I was trying to add a omnidirectional dash to my game with this code

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_accept"):    
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO

    velocity = position.direction_to(get_global_mouse_position()) * 200
```

And it is only moving the player up and down

I expected it to move based on the mouse's position, it does but only on the y axis, not the x.
If I add move_and_slide() to the bottom, it moves along the x axis but not smoothly as it moves abruptly like a teleport.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you get the behavior you describe. However, I can point to a possible issue with the code: It mixes local an global spaces.

In this expression:

```
position.direction_to(get_global_mouse_position())
```

The `position` is relative to the parent `Node`. Meanwhile `get_global_mouse_position` is global. So use `global_position` instead:

```
global_position.direction_to(get_global_mouse_position())
```

The alternative would be to convert `get_global_mouse_position()` to local space with `to_local`, but `velocity` should be in global anyway (and it is not a position, so do not convert `velocity` with `to_global` either).